# Hive outer join and non-equality conditions

Tags: sql, hive

Given table1:

```
id  begin_date  end_date     foo
1   2016-01-01  2016-12-31   1
1   2017-01-01  2017-12-31   2
```

And table2:

```
id  event_date  bar
1   2016-01-01 100
```

I want:

```
  id   begin_date end_date   foo   bar
  1    2016-01-01 2016-12-31  1    100
  1    2017-01-01 2017-01-01  2    NULL
```

Normally, I'd just do an outer join:

```
    ...
table1 
left join table2 
on table1.id = table2.id
    and table2.event_date between table1.begin_date and table1.end_date
```

But Hive won't allow us to do this.  So I tried moving the date comparison down to a where clause, and adding an `OR event_date is null`:

```
...
table1
left join table2
on table1.id = table2.id
where
(table2.event_date is null OR
table2.event_date between table1.start_date and table1.end_date)
```

But it that ends up working like an inner join, so that I don't get the 2017 row back.  Am I doing something wrong, or is there another way to approach this?

Comment: left join -> left outer join

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean.  `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are the same thing.

Comment: you are correct, I'll explain what happens in an answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get the 2017 row because you drop it in your `where` clause - that row will not get a `null` in `event_date` and the dates condition is also false.

Following your example, if you want `bar` to be null - you'll need to move the condition to the select clause:

```
select t1.id, begin_date, end_date, foo, 
   if(table2.event_date is not null and 
      table2.event_date between table1.start_date and table1.end_date, bar, null) from 
table1 left join table2
on table1.id = table2.id;
```